# Check Permissions in FastAPI + Stawberry GraphQL

Tags: python, graphql, jwt, fastapi, strawberry-graphql

I'm using BasePermission decorator as specified in [documentation](https://strawberry.rocks/docs/guides/permissions).

```
@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field(permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def user(self) -> User:
        # get by token OFC
        return User(user_id=1, email="vladimir@cw.tech", first_name = "Vladimir", last_name = "Kirilov")
```

In my impementation I use [VerifyToken](https://auth0.com/blog/build-and-secure-fastapi-server-with-auth0/) class as described in FastAPI auth0 documentation.

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    message = "User is not authenticated"

    def has_permission(self, source: Any, info: Info, **kwargs) -> bool:
        print(source)
        print(info)
        token: str = Depends(token_auth_scheme)
        print(token)
        result = VerifyToken(token.credentials).verify()
        if result.get("status"):
            print(result)
            return False

        return True
```

So I'm trying to get and verify the BEARER from the request, but I'm not able to extract it to process it further and get the error, please advise.

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "'Depends' object has no attribute 'credentials'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "user"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You've moved the token retrieval from the function signature - FastAPI won't resolve random variables inside a method for you - those have to declared in some way through FastAPIs dependency hierarchy. You could probably just call the function/class directly instead of using `Depends` in this case?

Comment: @MatsLindh hey thanks, but how should I extract the BEARER from GRAPHQL request?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, not the cleanest way, but here it is

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    message = "User is not authenticated"
    
    async def has_permission(self, source: Any, info: Info, **kwargs) -> bool:


        request: Union[Request, WebSocket] = info.context["request"]
        print(request.headers)
        if "Authorization" in request.headers:
            print(request.headers['Authorization'])
            result = VerifyToken( request.headers['Authorization'][7:] ).verify()
            if result.get("status") == "error":
                print(result.get("msg"))
                return False
            if result.get("sub"):
                print(result)
                return True
        return False
```